# Joomla Website+FTP through IE browser

Tags: database, internet-explorer, ftp, joomla

I've been asked to send my data through IE's ftp. I am inside the server already (with the username and password that it was given to me), but I don't know exactly what I have to copy there.
How do I copy the database? copy paste it? how about the folder in htdocs? copy paste too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using any hosting service you probably mus have access to any control panel like CPanel, in there you would find every administration option that can be use it to deploy your web sites or web application. Database administration can't be done over IE, like i said you must have access to hosting control panel.

Comment: The hosting server is one of the company where I am working. I don't have access to any CPanel. They only gave me the link to access through FTP, a username and a password. I've done it in IE and accessed a place where I can create folders, put files there, etc.

Comment: Ok that would help you to install just the application files. but if you need to install any database, you need ask for a database access path, login and password and access to it remotely

Comment: I don't get it. Let me try to explain again. I've made a website in Joomla in my laptop - localhost only. Now, I want to put it only on the companies' server, which they granted me access to, to put the key files to make the joomla website online.

Comment: Nevermind, I managed to contact an old friend of mine who helped me. Thanks anyway, worth the effort.